# Possible to change app icon without recompiling the APK?

Tags: android

Does anyone know if it is possible to open the APK file, access its /res/drawable directory and replace the icon.png with another icon.png image?

Is there any way for non-coder to change the icon.png without opening the project and recompiling?

So far, I had no success in this.

Comment: Did you check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081119/android-change-app-icon-programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, as the pointer to the icon is set in code. Are you wanting to change the icon of someone elses app?

Comment: No, my programming-illiterate customer want to do for his app I coded and he does not want to pay for any extra services. I knew it's not possible, but said why not ask it here.

Comment: ahhh, tell him you can do it, but it'd cost the same as swapping out the new image and recompiling it. It'd take more more than 5 minutes lol.