# Arrange Icons in Application Code?

Tags: android, mobile, launcher

Is it possible to arrange Android application icons on the home screen from application level code? Does this need to be handled by a custom launcher?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081119/android-change-app-icon-programatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851274/how-to-change-launcher-icon-and-its-label-from-the-application

Comment: you should definitely search first before posting a new question.

Comment: Those all only talk about the app icon. I want to rearrange all apps on the home screen of my device at run time.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that. The arrangement of the launcher icons is an implementation detail of the launcher app. Further, it depends on the specific launcher in use which can be wide and varied.

As you say, if you want to do that, you need to **be** the launcher app.